# Compiling a condition (once) for multicolumns pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I put a condition for one column in pandas dataframe, hopefully it works. But it doesn't work when I apply it for all columns.
For example we have a following dataframe called temps:

```
temps
              t  t_0  t_1
2012-07-16  260  250  210
2012-07-17  230  251  212
2012-07-18  265  220  250
2012-07-19  270  260  210
```

It works when I specified one column:

```
df_new = temps['t'][(temps['t'].values>(temps['t'].mean()-1.0*temps['t'].std())) 
       & (temps['t'].values<(temps['t'].mean()+1.0*temps['t'].std()))]

df_new
                t
2012-07-16    260
2012-07-18    265
2012-07-19    270
```

I would appreciate if someone guide me how can I do it once for all columns?  The following doesn't work of course.

```
df_new = temps[(temps.values>(temps.mean()-1.0*temps.std())) 
       & (temps.values<(temps.mean()+1.0*temps.std()))]
```

The expected output is:

```
df_new
                 t   t_0   t_1
2012-07-16     210   250   210
2012-07-19     210   260   210
```

or

```
df_new
                 t   t_0   t_1
2012-07-16     210   250   210
2012-07-17     nan   251   212
2012-07-18     265   nan   nan
2012-07-19     210   260   210
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a lazy way to make your code work with the least change possible:

```
temps2 = temps.copy()
for col in temps2.columns:
    temps2[col] = temps[col][(temps[col].values>(temps[col].mean()-1.0*temps[col].std())) 
                & (temps[col].values<(temps[col].mean()+1.0*temps[col].std()))]

              t  t_0  t_1
2012-07-16  260  250  210
2012-07-17  NaN  251  212
2012-07-18  265  NaN  NaN
2012-07-19  270  260  210
```

And here's a more elegant way:

```
zscore = temps.apply( lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std() )

                   t       t_0       t_1
2012-07-16  0.208683  0.272618 -0.533286
2012-07-17 -1.460778  0.330011 -0.431708
2012-07-18  0.486926 -1.449180  1.498279
2012-07-19  0.765169  0.846551 -0.533286

temps[ abs(zscore) < 1 ]

              t  t_0  t_1
2012-07-16  260  250  210
2012-07-17  NaN  251  212
2012-07-18  265  NaN  NaN
2012-07-19  270  260  210
```